# Pass parent id to relationship factory?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, factory

I have a factory of `posts` and a factory of `posts_images`, a post can have many images, I did create a seeder for posts that look like this.

```
$posts = factory(App\Models\Post::class, 100)->create()
->each(function($post) {
    $post->images()->saveMany(factory(App\Models\PostsImage::class, 3)->make());
});
```

I want to create `100 posts` and that each post have `3 images`, this kind of work, the problem is when the image is created

I want the image to be created from a base_64 string and saved in certain directory but I need the `id` of the `post` so I can create the folder where it will be created.

```
$factory->define(App\Models\PostsImage::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    //this does not get me the id
    $id = factory(\App\Models\Post::class)->make()->id;
    $name      = time();
    $b64_image = \Config::get('constants.seed_image');
    $data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $b64_image));
    if(!file_exists(public_path('images/eventos/'.$id.'/'))) {
        mkdir(public_path('images/noticias/'.$id.'/'));
    }
    file_put_contents(public_path('images/noticias/'.$id.'/'.$name.'.jpg'), $data);
    return [
        //
        'image'   => $name,
        'order'   => $id + 1
    ];
});
```

The only line that seems not to be working is

```
$id = factory(\App\Models\Post::class)->make()->id;
```

I did try using `create` instead of `make`, but this create more rows in the `post` table, and I don't want that.

Is there a way to pass the `post` `id` to the images factory?

Comment: if you are doing `make` you will never have an `id` because you are not saving it, just creating an instance of that class

Comment: exactly @matiaslauriti, so the id will only be available upon creation.

Comment: @ElishaSenoo this `factory(\App\Models\Post::class)->make()->id` will return null

Comment: $post->id, as in my answer below, has the id

Answer (score 0):

The best option will be to create the directory in the `posts` seeder, since you have the access to the `$post` object when a `Post` is created. Try something like this:

```
$posts = factory(App\Models\Post::class, 100)->create()
->each(function($post) {
    //id is available on the $post object created
    $id = $post->id;
    $name      = time();
    $b64_image = \Config::get('constants.seed_image');
    $data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $b64_image));
    if(!file_exists(public_path('images/eventos/'.$id.'/'))) {
        mkdir(public_path('images/noticias/'.$id.'/'));
    }
    file_put_contents(public_path('images/noticias/'.$id.'/'.$name.'.jpg'), $data);
    $post->images()->saveMany(factory(App\Models\PostsImage::class, 3)->make());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do usually in this situation is to get the last record of the created parent object.

```
$factory->define(App\Models\PostsImage::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    // get last record of Post
    $id = \App\Models\Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->id;
    $name      = time();
    $b64_image = \Config::get('constants.seed_image');
    $data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $b64_image));
    if(!file_exists(public_path('images/eventos/'.$id.'/'))) {
        mkdir(public_path('images/noticias/'.$id.'/'));
    }
    file_put_contents(public_path('images/noticias/'.$id.'/'.$name.'.jpg'), $data);
    return [
        //
        'image'   => $name,
        'order'   => $id + 1
    ];
});
```